# Why must a program and all its statically defined systems built with the RISC-V Toolchain fit within a 2-GB address range?

Tags: linux, gcc, operating-system, elf, riscv

I am trying to build a 64-bit executable RISC-V ELF using the RISC-V toolchain with newlib and a linker script that places the text section at 0x100 and the data section starting at 0x100000000 (greater than the 2 GB limit). However, I get the following error:

```
relocation truncated to fit: R_RISCV_HI20 against symbol `__global_pointer$' defined in .sdata section in a.out
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I noticed that the RISC-V options specify these two --mcmodel options:

```
-mcmodel=medlow
    Generate code for the medium-low code model. The program and its statically defined symbols must lie within a single 2 GiB address range and must lie between absolute addresses -2 GiB and +2 GiB. Programs can be statically or dynamically linked. This is the default code model.

-mcmodel=medany
    Generate code for the medium-any code model. The program and its statically defined symbols must be within any single 2 GiB address range. Programs can be statically or dynamically linked.
```

However, I am confused why even with 64-bit registers, why cannot use the entire 64-bit address space within my executable. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are similar situations on other 64-bit platforms such as x86-64 and ARM64.

The normal way to load a static address is as a 32-bit immediate, either absolute or pc-relative.  This is more efficient than requiring 64-bit immediates every time an address is used, which tend to need a longer and slower sequence of instructions.  But it does mean that all static code and data needs to fit in 2 GB.

You can use much more of the 64-bit address space for dynamically allocated objects, since they don't need their addresses coded into the binary.  This limit is only for **static** code and data.  Also, I'm not sure about RISC-V, but I believe on other platforms, the 2 GB limit applies separately to each shared library, so a really huge application could still be written by breaking off pieces into shared libraries.

On x86-64 and ARM64, GCC does support a "large" code model in which all static addresses are loaded as 64-bit, with the corresponding performance penalty.  It looks like this is not currently supported for RISC-V.